# Проблема с преобразованием h5 в pb

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Имею проблему с преобразованием модели h5 в tensorflow pb.
Пробовал использовать `freeze_session`, но постоянно сталкиваюсь с ошибками.

Вот участок кода:

```
model = tfk.models.load_model('model.h5')

frozen_graph = freeze_session(K.get_session(),
                              output_names=[out.op.name for out in model.outputs])

tf.python.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, "C:\+ " + "Users" + "\Me\someAI", "my_model.pb", as_text=False)
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/someAI/script.py", line 26, in <module>
    frozen_graph = freeze_session(K.get_session(),
  File "C:\Users\Me\someAI\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 171, in get_session
    default_session = tf.get_default_session()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как я могу ее исправить?

---

PS Сейчас имею tensorflow 1.14.0, keras 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [`tf.compat.v1.get_default_session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/get_default_session):

```
In [34]: tf.compat.v1.get_default_session?
Signature: tf.compat.v1.get_default_session()
Docstring:
Returns the default session for the current thread.

The returned `Session` will be the innermost session on which a
`Session` or `Session.as_default()` context has been entered.

NOTE: The default session is a property of the current thread. If you
create a new thread, and wish to use the default session in that
thread, you must explicitly add a `with sess.as_default():` in that
thread's function.

Returns:
  The default `Session` being used in the current thread.
```

Comment: Попробовал!
Но теперь проблема с функцией freeze_session AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'graph'